# Is it possible to prove that $K\subseteq C(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $K\lhd G$ and $K\cap G'=1$ ($G'$ is the commutator subgroup of G) then we can prove that $K$ is an abelian group: $K\cong K⁄1=K⁄K \cap G'\cong KG'⁄G' ≤G∕G'$.
However, is it possible to prove that $K\subseteq C(G)$ when $C(G)$ is the center of $G$?

Comment: Yes, try to compute a commutator between an element from $K$ and an arbitrary element from the group. What must this be contained in?

Comment: What do you mean?  
Should I compute $k(gkg^{-1} k^{-1}) g$  when $k\in K$  and $g\in G$?  
How?

Comment: $kgk^{-1}g^{-1}=k(gk^{-1}g^{-1})\in K$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\;\;K\lhd G\iff [K,G]:=\langle\;[k,g]\;;\;g\in G\;,\;k\in K\;\rangle\le K\\{}\\
(2)&\;\;\forall\,g\in G\;,\;\;[k,g]\in K\;\;\bf{\text{and also}}\;\;[k,g]\in G'\;,\;\;\text{ so...}\end{align*}$$

Note that point (1) is true for **any** group $\;G\;$ and **any** normal subgroup.

Comment: So... since $K\cap G'=1$, $G'=${1} and therefore G abelian group and $K\subseteq C(G)$?

Comment: No...where did you take that from?? Since $\;K\cap G'=1\implies [k,g]:=k^{-1}g^{-1}kg=1\iff kg=gk\;$ ...